# How to fix exception: Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory?

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j

I am trying to write a java web crawler for semantic web using jena library. I have build project using Netbeans. I am receiving two errors:

1. Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory
   Reported exception:
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Level
2. Could not initialize class com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom
   at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:128)

I have included `slf4j-api` and `slf4j-log` both libraries.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should also include `log4j` library as `slf4j-log4j` is just a static binder.

Answer (score 6):

You should include `slf4j-api-x.x.x.jar` and `slf4j-simple-x.x.x.jar` in your classpath.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all permutation and combination but finally **slf4j-api-** and **slf4j-simple-** worked well.

Answer (score 0):

As error suggested:

> Failed to instantiate [SLF4J](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLF4J) [LoggerFactory](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/LoggerFactory.html)

you need to place your corresponding `slf4j-*-*.jar` binding files into your [classpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29) folder.

You can locate them by `locate slf4j` if present.

> As of SLF4J version 1.6.0, if no binding is found on the class path, then slf4j-api will default to a no-operation implementation discarding all log requests.

#### Tomcat

If using Tomcat, these files you can copy either into `/usr/share/tomcat7/lib` or your webapp folder `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/*/WEB-INF/lib`.

#### Solr

If you're using Solr or you want use the files from there (which are included by default), you can find them in `dist/solrj-lib` and `example/lib/ext`.

---

See: [The Simple Logging Facade for Java (SLF4J) user manual](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html)