# Zookeeper 3.5.10 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jute/OutputArchive

Tags: apache-zookeeper

The error I get is the following in zookeeper 3.5.10 the lib directory has the zookeeper-jute-3.5.10.jar in the class path:

`Sat Feb 11 02:10:41 UTC 2023   INFO    Cleanup task completed Sat Feb 11 02:10:41 UTC 2023    ERROR   Cleanup Task:   ... 6 more Sat Feb 11 02:10:41 UTC 2023    ERROR   Cleanup Task:   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) Sat Feb 11 02:10:41 UTC 2023    ERROR   Cleanup Task:   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352) Sat Feb 11 02:10:41 UTC 2023    ERROR   Cleanup Task:   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) Sat Feb 11 02:10:41 UTC 2023    ERROR   Cleanup Task:   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387) Sat Feb 11 02:10:41 UTC 2023    ERROR   Cleanup Task: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Level Sat Feb 11 02:10:41 UTC 2023    ERROR   Cleanup Task:   at org.apache.zookeeper.server.PurgeTxnLog.<clinit>(PurgeTxnLog.java:47) Sat Feb 11 02:10:41 UTC 2023    ERROR   Cleanup Task:   at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:388) Sat Feb 11 02:10:41 UTC 2023    ERROR   Cleanup Task:   at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:362) Sat Feb 11 02:10:41 UTC 2023    ERROR   Cleanup Task:   at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:417) Sat Feb 11 02:10:41 UTC 2023    ERROR   Cleanup Task:   at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124) Sat Feb 11 02:10:41 UTC 2023    ERROR   Cleanup Task:   at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150) Sat Feb 11 02:10:41 UTC 2023    ERROR   Cleanup Task: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Level Sat Feb 11 02:10:41 UTC 2023    ERROR   Cleanup Task:   ... 6 more Sat Feb 11 02:10:41 UTC 2023    ERROR   Cleanup Task:   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) Sat Feb 11 02:10:41 UTC 2023    ERROR   Cleanup Task:   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352) Sat Feb 11 02:10:41 UTC 2023    ERROR   Cleanup Task:   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) Sat Feb 11 02:10:41 UTC 2023    ERROR   Cleanup Task:   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387) Sat Feb 11 02:10:41 UTC 2023    ERROR   Cleanup Task: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Level Sat Feb 11 02:10:41 UTC 2023    ERROR   Cleanup Task:   at org.apache.zookeeper.server.PurgeTxnLog.<clinit>(PurgeTxnLog.java:47) Sat Feb 11 02:10:41 UTC 2023    ERROR   Cleanup Task:   at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:388) Sat Feb 11 02:10:41 UTC 2023    ERROR   Cleanup Task:   at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:362) Sat Feb 11 02:10:41 UTC 2023    ERROR   Cleanup Task:   at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:417) Sat Feb 11 02:10:41 UTC 2023    ERROR   Cleanup Task:   at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124) Sat Feb 11 02:10:41 UTC 2023    ERROR   Cleanup Task:   at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150) Sat Feb 11 02:10:41 UTC 2023    ERROR   Cleanup Task: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Level Sat Feb 11 02:10:41 UTC 2023    ERROR   Cleanup Task: Reported exception: Sat Feb 11 02:10:41 UTC 2023    ERROR   Cleanup Task: Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory Sat Feb 11 02:05:41 UTC 2023    INFO    Cleanup task completed Sat Feb 11 02:05:41 UTC 2023    ERROR   Cleanup Task:   ... 6 more Sat Feb 11 02:05:41 UTC 2023    ERROR   Cleanup Task:   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) Sat Feb 11 02:05:41 UTC 2023    ERROR   Cleanup Task:   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352) Sat Feb 11 02:05:41 UTC 2023    ERROR   Cleanup Task:   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) Sat Feb 11 02:05:41 UTC 2023    ERROR   Cleanup Task:   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387) Sat Feb 11 02:05:41 UTC 2023    ERROR   Cleanup Task: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  ........... Sat Feb 11 01:55:41 UTC 2023    ERROR   Cleanup Task: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Level Sat Feb 11 01:55:41 UTC 2023    ERROR   Cleanup Task: Reported exception: Sat Feb 11 01:55:41 UTC 2023    ERROR   Cleanup Task: Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory`

Zookeeper comes up but this error is thrown, want to clear it.  But not sure how to determine which  jar is missing.

Fails -  Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory.  This version uses Reload4j.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix exception: Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246157/how-to-fix-exception-failed-to-instantiate-slf4j-loggerfactory)

Comment: no, also did  a check on the `docker pull zookeeper:3.5.10; docker run ...-d zookeeperL3.5.10; docker exec -it {name} /bin/bash  and compared the jars... no joy.