# Gradle: Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory error

Tags: java, gradle

As I mentioned in title, projects on my local which are using Gradle started to throw this error:

```
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Process command line: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_221.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xms256m -Xmx512m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=GB -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp /Users/loaner/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.2-bin/6xuflze0i9mjovrm0ys9asj72/gradle-6.2/lib/gradle-launcher-6.2.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 6.2
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory
Reported exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/core/joran/spi/JoranException
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:412)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
    at org.gradle.api.logging.Logging.getLogger(Logging.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonMain.<clinit>(DaemonMain.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:58)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon.main(GradleDaemon.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.JoranException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 14 more
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.tryClose(ClassLoaderUtils.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:64)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon.main(GradleDaemon.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory in failed state. Original exception was thrown EARLIER. See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#unsuccessfulInit
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:422)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.CompositeStoppable.<clinit>(CompositeStoppable.java:37)
    ... 4 more

-----------------------
Check the JVM arguments defined for the gradle process in:
 - gradle.properties in project root directory
```

And I cannot figure out how to solve it.

What I have tried so far;

- Removed and installed intellij
- Tried with a fresh repo
- Removed gradle cache
- Added log4j and slf4j libraries I found as a solution on SO.
- [How to fix exception: Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246157/how-to-fix-exception-failed-to-instantiate-slf4j-loggerfactory)
- [Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388078/failed-to-instantiate-slf4j-loggerfactory)

IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.3 (Community Edition)
java version "1.8.0_221"

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you have an invalid Gradle installation.

Assuming you are using the Gradle wrapper, I would remove the content of `$HOME/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-<gradle-version>` and try again with running the project.

If you are not using the Gradle wrapper, but an installed version, I would remove it and re-install.